# Splitting Datetime into a date and a time value

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone give me a quick and dirty way to split a datetime (28-1-2011 14:32:55) into just the date (28-1-2011) and the time ( 14:32 ) or even better (2:32 PM) using PHP. Using a mySQL database as well.

Cheers

Comment: What do you mean by "a datetime" exactly? A string, or a `DateTime` object?

Comment: I have a popup calender on my webpage and it returns a string as 28-1-2011 14:32:55. But in my database I have a Date column and a Time column. So in PHP i just want to split them into 2 separate variables.

Comment: You can just split the spring into an array by space - explode(' ',$datestring). Below answers are better, but this one focuses on being "quick" and "dirty".

Answer (score 26):

If you're using PHP > 5.2:

```
$myvalue = '28-1-2011 14:32:55';

$datetime = new DateTime($myvalue);

$date = $datetime->format('Y-m-d');
$time = $datetime->format('H:i:s');
```

Prior to PHP 5.2 [mhitza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532069/splitting-datetime-into-a-date-and-a-time-value/5532139#5532139) gave a good answer.

Comment: (sidenote) Be aware that DateTime object uses default time zone set in php.ini, if not changed by code. Always set time zone! However, this is correct code for +1.

Comment: Anybody have thoughts of overhead of this verses using date_parse()

Answer (score 10):

if your source of data is MySQL:

```
SELECT DATE( date_field ) AS date_part, TIME( date_field ) AS time_part ....
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

Edit :
to answer the question from comments (example):

```
WHERE DATE( date_field ) > '2017-01-01'
```

Comment: Yup... get the answer already split from the query instead of duplicating the effort by parsing back in PHP.

Comment: It is faster but sometimes you need to do it in PHP.

Comment: how to use `date_part`  in `where` condition??

Answer (score 9):

In php you can use the `date` and `strtotime` functions for easy extraction.

```
$datetime = "28-1-2011 14:32:55";
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($datetime));
$time = date('H:i:s', strtotime($datetime));
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple instruction will do the trick

explode will transform datetime to an array

and list will sort the datetime array into its needed values

```
$datetime = "28-1-2011 14:32:55";
list($date, $time)=explode(' ', $datetime);

// check the result
echo "date:". $date;
echo "<br>time:". $time;

// further more you can easily split the date into 
// year month and day 
list($year, $month, $day)=explode('-', $date);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for a really quick and dirty solution.

```
$datetime = "28-1-2011 14:32:55";
$date_arr= explode(" ", $datetime);
$date= $date_arr[0];
$time= $date_arr[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

> if you want to parse in the date from your Mysql and you want to remove time
>   then you can use this function

```
$date1=date("Y-m-d",strtotime('$your database field'))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can easily split DateTime(28-1-2011 14:32:55) into date and time in MySQL.

```sql
select SUBSTRING_INDEX("28-1-2011 14:32:55", " ",1) into @dateOnly;

select @dateOnly;
```

The output will be- **28-1-2011**(Here we split the date from the DateTime)

```sql
select SUBSTRING_INDEX("28-1-2011 14:32:55", " ",-1) into @timeOnly;

select @timeOnly;
```

The output will be- **14:32:55**(Here we split the time from the DateTime)

We can covert the time to am and pm format also

```sql
select SUBSTRING_INDEX("28-1-2011 14:32:55", " ",-1) into @timeOnly;

SELECT TIME_FORMAT(@timeOnly, "%h %i %s %p")into @time;

select @time;
```

The time format will become **02 32 55 PM**

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can split a datetime string into date and time components using the `date()` and `strtotime()` functions along with `DateTime` objects for better formatting. (=

```php
$datetimeString = '28-1-2011 14:32:55';

// Splitting into date and time
$date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($datetimeString)); // Date format: 28-1-2011
$time24 = date('H:i', strtotime($datetimeString)); // Time format (24-hour): 14:32
$time12 = date('h:i A', strtotime($datetimeString)); // Time format (12-hour with AM/PM): 02:32 PM

echo "Date: $date<br>";
echo "Time (24-hour format): $time24<br>";
echo "Time (12-hour format): $time12";
```

`strtotime()` converts the string to a Unix timestamp.
`date()` formats the timestamp into the desired date or time format.
`d-m-Y` in `date('d-m-Y')` represents the day-month-year format for the date.
`H:i` in `date('H:i')` represents the 24-hour format for the time (hours:minutes). `h:i A` in `date('h:i A')` represents the 12-hour format with AM/PM.