# Split string time and date

Tags: php, mysql

I need to split time and date from 2015-01-25 21:00. I want to split it to $year, $month, $day and $time. I always end up with on the date: 25 21:00. So i want 4 different variables.

Comment: Wait, we'll imagine your code.

Comment: You may want to have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). Here's a quick example on how to break it out.

```
   $date = strtotime('2015-01-25 21:00');
   $year = date('Y', $date);
   $month = date('m', $date);
   $day = date('d', $date);
   $time = date('H:i', $date);
```

I would read the links above to get a better understanding of the requirements. All date strings should be handled this way to ensure accuracy. Also if you start modifying the date by +/- days/months/years you should modify off of your `$date` var and not off of the new ones that you created.

While preg_match and explode from the answers below may work on giving you results, they will be almost impossible to handle the data as a date for any use case you may have.

Answer (score 1):

```
select year(datetime_column) as year,
       month(datetime_column) as month,
       day(datetime_column) as day,
       time(datetime_column) as time
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you don't want to do the actual splitting in MySQL? Either way I think this type of question has multiple answers already.

PHP solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5532150/3249252).

```
$myvalue = '28-1-2011 14:32:55';

$datetime = new DateTime($myvalue);

$date = $datetime->format('Y-m-d');
$time = $datetime->format('H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a preg match, you probably want to cast the values to int.

```
preg_match('/([0-9]{4})\-([0-9]{2})\-([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2})/', $date, $match);
$year = $match[1];
$month = $match[2];
$day = $match[3];
$time = $match[4];
```

Comment: While this may work, this is not how you should handle dates / times

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$datetime = '2015-01-25 21:00';
$datetime_array = explode(' ',$datetime);
$date = $datetime_array[0];
$time = $datetime_array[1];
$arr = explode('-', $date);
$year = $arr[0];
$month = $arr[1];
$day = $arr[2];
echo 'Year: '.$year.' Month: '.$month.' Day: '.$day.' Time: '.$time;
```

Output:

```
Year: 2015 Month: 01 Day: 25 Time: 21:00
```