# Splitting the time into hours and minutes with meridians

Tags: php, time

Since in the form in an html has an input type time. Then it displays the 24 hours or military time. Then how should 24 hour time into 12 hour time with the meridians (AM and PM)? And how can I split the input type time into hours and minutes with meridians (AM and PM)?

Comment: I have used pure PHP. Just check my answer

Comment: hope you understand it. Let me know if it works

Comment: I've tried the codes in the post that you linked, then what happened is that it displays the military hour and the meridian if it is AM or PM, then suddenly when i look at my database, it stores their only the military , not converted into 12 hour, my data type in my database is in Time,

Comment: Refer this document.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx

You might have to change the value taken from the DB before displaying to user

Comment: okay i am opening it.. actually i will ask also this one

Comment: I am coding about the log out . then after that, i found out that when i log out, it goes to the log in page, but when i press the back button, it will go back again to the previous page. How should i avoid this case and situation to be happened again?

Comment: How do you check whether the user is logged in or not?? Or you can user a session variable

Comment: i check by making my own account to my created site then i tried to log in and log out, then the problem is that i went back to the previous page when i log out

Comment: Ok. Can you show me some code work. then I can give you my solution

Comment: this is for log out                                                                                                    <?php
 require('connect.php');
 session_start(); //Start the current session
 session_destroy(); //Destroy it! So we are logged out now
 header("location:admin_login.php"); // Move back to login.php with a logout message
?>

Comment: how can i trap that one so that i will not go back to the previous page when i log out

Comment: come for chat. I'll tell you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/fexw2qeL/)**

Using Javascript can be done..

```
 var dt = new Date();
    var h=dt.getHours();
    var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();
    alert(time);
    if(h<12)
    {alert(time+":AM");
    }else
    {
        alert(time+":PM");}
```

Comment: can we use the PHP in separating the time?

Comment: sorry dude..php i cant help..you can use jquery right..may be someone will help you for php

Comment: I did not still know how to use Jquery since we did not tackle that one. How about javascript. can we use that?

Comment: is it a function? then if it is so, then how can i call that in PHP to get the conditions inside the function?

Comment: If you find it is difficult to implement.. then read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378792/split-time-into-3-variables http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532069/splitting-datetime-into-a-date-and-a-time-value  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14457250/php-splitting-the-date-and-time-within-a-timestamp-value-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
$format_timestamp=date("h:i A", strtotime($_POST['my_input'])); 

echo $format_timestamp;
```

$_POST['my_input'] is the input value you take from the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
$time = '19:24:00'; //input of user
 $yourtime =  date('h:i a', strtotime($time)); //convert to 12 hours
preg_match("/([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2}) ([a-zA-Z]+)/", $yourtime, $match); // split the hour and min and am/pm 
$hour = $match[1];
$min = $match[2];
$ampm = $match[3];

print_r($hour.':'.$min.':'.$ampm); //output
```

Answer (score 0):

For Sever side time you can use PHP code as below.

```
<?php
    echo $time = date("h:i A");
?>
```

For client side time you can use javascript code as below

```
<script>
var dt = new Date();
var h=dt.getHours();
var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();

if(h<12)
{
   alert(time+":AM");
}
else
{
   alert(time+":PM");
}
```

both solutions give diffrent time as per required.